# Need a Regular Expression to validate a hostname and port to be used with TcpClient.Connect()

Tags: c#, regex

The title pretty much says it all.

To clarify, the expression must match something like this:

```
127.0.0.1:8888
```

Or this:

```
localhost:8888
```

The hostname and port must be valid, but they also must be in a string that's constructed like the ones above, colon and all.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what's to stop a syntactically valid hostname from not being a real hostname?

Comment: @Cameron I already tried an expression that I found on the web, but it allows full URLs and all that... not what I need. As to your second question, that's completely irrelevant. It would be up to our clients to provide a valid hostname if they want our system to work for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern  should match either the a standard IPv4 address or the text *'localhost'* as well as the port number.

```
public static bool IsValidHostAddress(string hostAddress)
{
    const string Pattern =  @"^(([0-9]{1,3}.){3}([0-9]{1,3})|localhost):\d+$";

    var regex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return regex.Match(hostAddress).Success;
}
```

Comment: I mistakenly selected this before I realized it was incorrect. Even if `localhost` is the value, it still needs the port number after it. How can I modify this to meet that requirement?

Comment: @kehrk Updated the answer with my own pattern. The pattern will not ensure that the octals do not exceed the maximum of 255 nor will the pattern ensure that the port number does not exceed the maximum port number of 65535. Doing so would increase the complexity of the pattern considerably. Is that important to you?