# Regex Pattern - allow ',' and ':' after ip and hostname

Tags: c#, regex

I have following regex for ip validation:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

and regex for hostname validation:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

How I have to change them, to allow validation:

1) Ip - **172.17.1.1:80** and **172.17.1.1,80** and **172.17.1.1**

2) Hostname - **machineName:80**, and **machineName,80** and **machineName**

Comment: which language are you using!

Comment: @Anirudth I'm using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553003/need-a-regular-expression-to-validate-a-hostname-and-port-to-be-used-with-tcpcli)

```
public static bool IsValidHostAddress(string hostAddress)
{
    const string Pattern =  @"^(([0-9]{1,3}.){3}([0-9]{1,3})|localhost):\d+$";
    var regex = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return regex.Match(hostAddress).Success;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to flag a stack as a duplicate if it has already been answered!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [`Uri.CheckHostName(string name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname.aspx) method?

> Determines whether the specified host name is a valid DNS name.

The parameter name has the following documentation:

> The host name to validate. This can be an IPv4 or IPv6 address or an Internet host name.