# regular expression checking valid hostname port

Tags: regex

I've searched thru various websites and here for one that works but none do.

I need a regex that validates a game server hostname is correct format.

Example:

```
gost.gflclan.com:27015
```

And also the normal ip:port

```
103.18.138.27:27015
```

The hostname version can also have numbers in the subdomain or main part. And always has 5 numbers in port on both.

I've currently got this but it only works for the ip:port and not the hostname one.

```
([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{5})|([a-z].[a-z].[a-z]:[1-9]{5})
```

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: RegEx isn't meant to do these 2 totally separate string matching in 1. What kind of coding-language are you using? You need a detection mechanism to let it check if either domainname or ip-based validation has passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a Regular Expression to validate a hostname and port to be used with TcpClient.Connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553003/need-a-regular-expression-to-validate-a-hostname-and-port-to-be-used-with-tcpcli)

Comment: Not much point in this. Even if it's syntactically valid it can still be wrong. Just try to connect and let the exception(s) tell you what's wrong with it, if anything.

Answer (score 3):

**updated :**

try:

```
[^\:]+:[0-9]{5}
```

dynamically match both:

```
103.18.138.27:27015
gost.gflclan.com:27015
```

little explaination:

```
 [^\:]+ --- |> all chars till ':' 
   :
 [0-9]{5} --|> exactly 5 numbers
```

Comment: Shouldn't you match against any number of characters? Port 80, for example, or port 443, are both valid

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit more cleaner code:

```
(([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})|(\w*.\w*.\w*)):[0-9]{5}
```

Comment: Won't match `example.com:1234`

Answer (score 0):

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/cC0eQ3/1)

You forgot the `+` after `[a-z]` and the dot must be escaped:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{5})|([a-z]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\:[0-9]{5})
```