# Regex for valid host:port form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I did't found yet somethig that fits to my need, I need a regex that varify host:port.

for example:

```
localhost:52247  //true
web.mycompany.com //true
web.mycompany.com:52247 //true
192.168.108.76:8383/ //true
192.168.108.76/ //true
```

and should return false for the following;

```
localhost:9999999  //false because port is not valid
'' //false becuse string is empty
web.mycoעעעעעmpany.com:52247 //false because it contains hebrew characters
192.168.377.76:8383/ //false because ip address not valid
```

Comment: I don't see that much use here. It'll be very hard to validate and even if it's syntactically valid it can still be wrong. Also seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966391/regular-expression-checking-valid-hostname-port/25966545

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regular expression checking valid hostname port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966391/regular-expression-checking-valid-hostname-port)

Comment: @FelixGerberding both commnts are for same link. this doesn't answer to my question since the answers in the link doesn't match to my list. in the answer port must be provided

Comment: Why write your own regex, when https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL already exists? https://jsfiddle.net/g3q6fk5a/

Comment: @CBroe how can I use `URL` as a validation?

Comment: Check the fiddle I provided.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, you can write this as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not write my own regular expression here, but use the [`URL()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) - that will throw a TypeError exception, if the provided parameter is not considered a valid URL.

Your input values would just have to be prefixed with a protocol, to make them valid, *non-relative* URLs in the first place - so let’s just put `http://` in front, and then see if the constructor throws an exception, or not:

```js
var urls = 'localhost:52247,web.mycompany.com,web.mycompany.com:52247,192.168.108.76:8383/,192.168.108.76/,localhost:9999999,,web.mycoעעעעעmpany.com:52247,192.168.377.76:8383/'.split(',');

urls.forEach(function(e){
  try {
    new URL('http://'+e);
    console.log(e + ": true");
  }
  catch(x) {
    console.log(e + ": false");
  }
})
```

Comment: URL API does not validate against HTTP protocol , hence this will incorrectly validate `http://foo(.com` as valid URL but it's invalid.